# error de bootstrap 4.5 no mantiene la maquetación correcta

Tags: php, css, css3, bootstrap-4

tengo un error al cambiar de tamaño para diferentes dispositivos, cuando esta en dispositivo mobile no respeta el ancho que le corresponde, pero a otros input si lo respeta y tengo que actualizar el navegador para que recién respete el ancho, aquí un ejemplo

https://ibb.co/jhK6smG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/plugins/select2/select2-bootstrap4.min.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
  <title>Reserva de citas medicas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bootsnav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/img/logo.png" alt="" loading="lazy"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cita Médica en Linea <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="innerheader-wrapp">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h3 class="my-1"><i class="fa fa-user-md fa-1x"></i> <span class="text-muted font-weight-light">Reserva tu cita </span>médica</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--   Big container   -->
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Paso 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Paso 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Paso 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h5>Despues de seleccionar el Servicio Médico y la Ciudad
                haga click en el "Paso 2"</h5>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <h5 style="color: #f1780e;">1. SELECCIONA EL <span>SERVICIO MÉDICO</span></h5>
                <select class="form-control mb-3" name="spe_name" id="spe_id">
                  <option value="0">Seleccione Servicio</option>
                  <?php foreach($specialties as $spe): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $spe->id ?>"><?php echo $spe->spe_name ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select> 
              </div> 
              <div class="form-group">          
                <h5 style="color: #f1780e;" class="mt-3">2. SELECCIONA LA <span>CIUDAD</span></h5>
                <select class="form-control mb-3" name="city_name" id="city_id">
                </select>
              </div>     
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h5>Despues de seleccionar la Clínica y el/la Doctor(a)
                haga click en el "Paso 3"</h5>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">                                
                <h5 style="color: #f1780e;">3. Clínica/Centro De Salud:</h5>
                <select class="form-control mb-3" name="address" id="cli_id">
                </select>                            
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">                                                        
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                  <h5 class="mt-3" style="color: #f1780e;">4. Doctor(a):</h5>
                  <select class="form-control mb-3" name="doctor_name" id="doc_id">
                  </select>                      
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <div align="center"><img src="" id="changeImage" width="75%"></div>
                </div>  
              </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                  <h5 style="color: #f1780e;">5. Fecha:</h5>
                  <div id="fecha_id">
                    
                  </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                  <h5 style="color: #f1780e;">6. Hora:</h5>
                  <select class="form-control mb-3" name="time_at" id="time_at">
                  </select>   
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                
                  <h5>Despues de seleccionar la <span class="nota">Fecha</span> y la <span class="nota">Hora</span> haga click en <span class="nota2">"Registrar Reserva"</span></h5>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="reservas" name="signup1" disabled="">REGISTRAR RESERVA</button>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <footer class="py-4 fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <p class="mb-0"><?php echo date("Y"); ?> © Derechos Reservados<a href="https://smartup.com.bo" target="_blank"> Sistemas en Oferta</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">base_url = '<?= base_url();?>'</script>
  <script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

como soluciono ese error aolamente en los primeros input no logra redimensionarse, pero en los demás input si se redimensiona, si se adapta al tamaño de la pantalla. no entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal si las clases usadas de bootstrap están bien, ayuda por favor...

Answer (score -1):

Hola lo que se me ocurre es que puedes darle un anchor máximo y aplicándole estilos al container de esta forma para que no choque o quede tan justo.

```
 <div class="container" style="width:80%">
```

Comment: Ya lo probé, sigue igual con el mismo problema

Comment: entonces debe ser tu navegador porque ami no me salen mal incluso sin el cambio me sale bien

Comment: estoy usando esta versión de navegador Google Chrome está actualizado
Versión 83.0.4103.97 (Build oficial) (64 bits)